# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when decrypting file

Tags: android, bouncycastle

Hi I am getting the following exception, when decrypting a file on Android based on user supplied password:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=1024 srcPos=1008 dst.length=16 dstPos=16 length=16
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.processBytes(PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.java:221)
        at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$BufferedGenericBlockCipher.processBytes(BaseBlockCipher.java:882)
        at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineUpdate(BaseBlockCipher.java:674)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(Cipher.java:893)
        at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.write(CipherOutputStream.java:95)
```

It happens randomly and from the crash reports on Google Play Store only on Android 4+. It used to work on older versions.

My Crypto wrapper:

```
private static final String KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "PBEWITHSHAAND128BITAES-CBC-BC";
private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String CIPHER_PROVIDER = "AES";

public Crypto(String password, byte[] salt) {

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "password cannot be null or empty.");
    }

    PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 20,
            128);

    SecretKeyFactory factory;
    try {
        factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        PBEKey key = (PBEKey) factory.generateSecret(keySpec);

        this.createKeyAndCipher(key.getEncoded());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void createKeyAndCipher(byte[] keyData)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException {
    _secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, KEY_ALGORITHM);
    _cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_PROVIDER);
}
```

And the function that does decryption:

```
public void decrypt(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
        throws Throwable {
    _cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, _secretKey);
    this.encryptDecrypt(input, output);
}

public void encryptDecrypt(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws Throwable {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    CipherOutputStream cipherStream = new CipherOutputStream(output,
            _cipher);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int count = -1;
    while ((count = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        cipherStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    input.close();
    cipherStream.close();
}
```

Did something change in Android 4 version of Boucycastle?

Any hints greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

### UPDATE:

Changed the code to this:

```
public void encryptDecrypt(InputStream input, OutputStream output) {
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int count = -1;
        while ((count = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            byte[] result = null;
            if (count == BUFFER_SIZE) {
                result = _cipher.update(buffer, 0, count);
            } else {
                result = _cipher.doFinal(buffer, 0, count);
            }

            if (result != null) {
                output.write(result);
            }
        }
        input.close();
        output.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
```

One thing should be noted: This ONLY happens when I try to decrypt the file. Short byte[] from sqlite decrypted by _cipher.doFinal(arra) works fine with the same key.

Also, in the original error at the beginning of the post,

```
dst.length=16 dstPos=16 length=16
```

I have read something somewhere about AES and data being shorter then 16.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Viswanath L, The provider is "BC" and when supplied to Cipher.getInstance() I still have the same problem. Randomly, even on the same file, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I was updating the link unable to edit, Android has changed encryption api in 4+ due to security constrains .please check this, you may have similar issues http://viswanathl.in/2014/01/encryption-and-decryption-using-aes-in-android/ read the paragragh after 1st chunk of code